# How does a BufferedReader interact with a Socket? About how Sockets work

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I have been following a tutorial on how to build a simple chat application in Java. I get the basic principle of how sever and client communicate. So far I used a PrintWriter to send, and a BufferedReader to recieve information for both sides. But what I don´t get is how this does not lead to errors?

```
Socket soc = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream));
while(true) {

    String str = in.readLine();

}
```

My question would be the following. Is the `in.readLine()` statement "waiting" for input? If it does not, shouldn´t the program throw Errors if using the `str` since it has no value? Or in general terms, do Socket specific functions like `Socket soc = serverSocket.accept();` or as in the example given above the reading of an InputStream  "wait" for a signal whatsoever? Did I miss some essential concept about Sockets? It would be great if someone could help me understand this topic further.

Thank you in advance,

Appa

Comment: I'm not trying to dissuade you from your current task -- but -- after you finish your current tutorial, I'd suggest using Java's NIO library. At my place of work we were about to release some new realtime event'ing for an older API/service done in Java ... and in the last 2 weeks we switched from the socket/socket-server that you're using to the "newer" NIO socket-channels and such.

https://crunchify.com/java-nio-non-blocking-io-with-server-client-example-java-nio-bytebuffer-and-channels-selector-java-nio-vs-io/

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'm fairly new to this topic and will definitely look into this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question would be the following. Is the in.readLine() statement "waiting" for input?

Yes, it is "waiting for input" since `.readLine()` is a *blocking* method

> If it does not, shouldn´t the program throw Errors if using the str since it has no value?

I cannot parse this -- the statement doesn't make sense. What error / exception would you be expecting?

> Or in general terms, do Socket specific functions like Socket soc = serverSocket.accept(); or as in the example given above the reading of an InputStream "wait" for a signal whatsoever?

Again, I'm afraid that this is not too clear (at least to me). `ServerSocket#accept()` *is* a blocking method and will wait until a socket connection can be made, if that is what you are asking.

---

Note that thiscode:

```
while(true) {
    String str = in.readLine();
}
```

while valid, would not be particularly useful, since you would be reading a String and then discarding it, doing nothing with it.  Better to either print the String obtained, or pass it into a method where it can be used in some way. On the other hand, I suppose this could be useful if all you wanted to do was to "gobble" the stream to prevent the OS's buffers from overflowing.

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I was asking. I wasn´t familiar with the concept of a blocking method. And thanks for the advice, I was about to add code to the while loop. Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes readLine does in fact block. It waits till you read a carriage return/line feed, or the socket closes.